# How can I send a form with jQuery

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax

I need to code an AJAX request with jQuery (3.2.1) and display email input value after the form was sended.
When I click on submit button, i have this following message, I didn't understand what is wrong with my code.

[image: Image of my error message]

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" id="myForm">
   <div class="form-line">
     <input type="email" name="emailaddress" id="emailaddress" />
   </div>
   <div id="emailMsg"></div>
      <div class="form-line">
         <input type="password" name="psw" id="password" />
         <button type="submit" id="submit"><span>OK</span></button>
      </div>
   <div id="passMsg"></div>
</form>
```

And this is what i have done on jQuery code

```
$("#myForm").on('submit',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var email = $("#emailaddress").val();

    $.post("../process.php", {
        emailaddress:emailaddress
    }, function(response) {
        $("#connexion-rollover").html(email);
    });
});
```

I have also create this PHP file to add this code

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['emailaddress'];
?>
```

I hope that my first message on this site was clear.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Try replace `emailaddress:emailaddress` for `emailaddress:email`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Benilson, I have this error on console right now : 
jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 POST http://127.0.0.1:8080/process.php 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Comment: No change, very weird. I take an screenshot of my php file and my folder organization.
https://prnt.sc/26jnv8q